# Regex to match non-whitespace around & in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a request query string which contains parameter name with `&` (`&name`) since in request query string, parameters also separated with `&`, then variable name is `&&name`. I wrote the regexp which is should return parameter value

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("&(&[^=]+)=([^&]*)").matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
String value = matcher.group(2);
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

So regexp works fine when request string has following construction:

```
  String str = "&&NAME=name 1&&NAME=name 2&type=1";
```

The output is:

```
name 1
name 2
```

But when the string has the following construction

```
String str = "&&NAME=name 1&&NAME=name & 2&type=1";
```

The output is:

```
name 1
name
```

I tried this:

```
 &(&[^=]+)=([^\\S&\\S]*)
```

`\\S` matches non-whitespace, but nor worked. How can I solve it?

Comment: I have a just a query string. I tried your regex but it does not work as i want. I replace the second group with yours : &(&[^=]+)=(.*?)(?=&&|$), but output is name 1  and name & 2&type=1

Comment: I added an answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this regex that will make sure we stop consuming characters into Group 2 if there is a non-whitespace character after `&`.

```
String rx = "&(&.*?)=(.*?)(?=&\\S|$)";
```

[IDEONE Demo](https://ideone.com/aEzGBA)

Output:

```
name 1
name & 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lookaround based regex:

```
(?<=&&|^).*?(?=&&|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wP2jJ5/1)